How to set the width of a specific column on a lightning-data table inside of a LWC?
I am displaying a table on a custom object and wish to set the width of each column in the table. There are only 3 columns. Here is my HTML inside the LWC that displays the table:
<template>
    <lightning-card variant="Narrow" icon-name="standard:survey">
        <h1 slot="title" class="slds-card__header-link">Survey Responses</h1>
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={data}
                hide-checkbox-column
                columns={columns} sorted-by={sortBy} 
                    sorted-direction={sortDirection}  onsort={handleSortdata} >
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>    
</template>

Here is the JS file:
import { LightningElement,wire, track, api } from 'lwc';

import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from 'lightning/pageReferenceUtils';

import getSurvey from '@salesforce/apex/SurveyResponseTableCtrl.getSurvey';



const columns = [
    { label: 'Question Order', fieldName: 'questionOrder',sortable: 'true', type: 'text' ,cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }},
    { label: 'Question', fieldName: 'question',sortable: 'true', type: 'text' ,wrap:'true',cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left',  }},
    { label: 'Answer', fieldName: 'answer',sortable: 'true', type: 'text' ,wrap:'true', cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }}
];

export default class surveyResponseTableLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    data = [];
    dataTemp = [];
    isShowData = false;
    columns = columns;
    @api recordId;
    @track sortBy;
    @track sortDirection;
    // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-await
    
     async connectedCallback() {
        getSurvey({recId: this.recordId})
                .then((result) => {
                    this.data = result;
                    this.error = undefined;
                    //sortData('respondedDate', 'desc');
                    sortData('questionOrder', 'asc');
                    console.log('data',data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.error = error;
                    
                });
    }
    handleSortdata(event) {
        // field name
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
        // sort direction
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
        // calling sortdata function to sort the data based on direction and selected field
        this.sortData(event.detail.fieldName, event.detail.sortDirection);
    }

    sortData(fieldname, direction) {
        //this.data = this.messageRecordList;
        this.dataTemp = this.data;
        console.log('this.data' +this.data);
        console.log('this.messageDataList ' +this.messageRecordList );

        // serialize the data before calling sort function
        //let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dataTemp));
        console.log('parseData' +parseData);

        // Return the value stored in the field
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };

        // cheking reverse direction 
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;

        // sorting data 
        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; // handling null values
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';

            // sorting values based on direction
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });

        // set the sorted data to data table data
        //this.data = parseData;
        this.data = parseData;
    }
}

Lastly, here is my apex class:
public class SurveyResponseTableCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<SurveyWrapper> getSurvey(string recId){

        List<SurveyWrapper> surveyResponseList  = new List<SurveyWrapper>();
        
        List<Survey_Response__c> sSurveyResponse = [Select Survey_Invitation_id__c from Survey_Response__c where Id = : recId];
        String sInvitiationId = sSurveyResponse[0].Survey_Invitation_id__c;


        List<SurveyQuestionResponse> surveyQuestionResponseList = new List<SurveyQuestionResponse>();
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            surveyQuestionResponseList = [SELECT Question.QuestionOrder , Question.Name,  ResponseValue FROM SurveyQuestionResponse  where InvitationId = :sInvitiationId order by Question.QuestionOrder asc];
        }
        else{
            List<Survey> SurveyTest = [SELECT Id, Name,ActiveVersionId FROM Survey];
            
            SurveyQuestionResponse sObj1 = new SurveyQuestionResponse();
            SurveyInvitation si = new SurveyInvitation(Id='0Ki3K0000004KcZSAU',Name = 'surveyInvitationTest1');
            surveyQuestionResponseList.add(sObj1);
        }
        for(SurveyQuestionResponse sObj : surveyQuestionResponseList){
            SurveyWrapper surveyWrap = new SurveyWrapper();
            surveyWrap.questionOrder = sObj.Question.QuestionOrder != null ? sObj.Question.QuestionOrder : 0;
            surveyWrap.question = sObj.Question.Name != null ? sObj.Question.Name : '';
            surveyWrap.answer = sObj.ResponseValue != null ?  sObj.ResponseValue : '';
            SurveyResponseList.add(surveyWrap);
        }
        return SurveyResponseList;
    }
    public class SurveyWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public integer questionOrder;
        @AuraEnabled
        public string question;
        @AuraEnabled
        public string answer;        
    }
}

All of this together generates a table that looks like this:

I would just like to simply edit the column width so that the Question Order column is smaller.

Use the initialWidth parameter if you want to specify a width, or fixedWidth if you want it to be a specific size and unable to resize. This is a number in pixels.
{ fixedWidth: 20, label: 'Question Order', fieldName: 'questionOrder',sortable: 'true', type: 'text' ,cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }},

You can read more in the documentation.

Thanks. That did it!
